# Do celery have backfill and catch up feature built in if not than how can we implement these features with celery?

Tags: celery

Do celery have backfill and catch up feature built in  if not than how can we implement these features with celery?

Can we execute our job in past date using celery or can we catch up using celery?
Backfill and catch up feature

Answer (score 0):

No - there is no such feature, and it makes no sense to make one. Why? Beucase any task that needs to run for data on particular date/time can take that as parameter.

Imagine you have a task called `parse_data` with some parameters, and say you need to run it daily. If it already does not take date as parameter, all you have to do is to add that parameter to the task, and you can run it for any date you like (even future dates, but that will most likely fail, as you do not have data needed for the parser job on a future date).